# Why am I getting different result from the code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a simple function that returns array of items.

```
function arrayFromValue(...item) {
    return item;
}

console.log(arrayFromValue(1, 2, 3));
```

The function works fine but, when wrote the code like this:

```
function arrayFromValue(...item) {
    return 
    item;
}

console.log(arrayFromValue(1, 2, 3));
```

it outputs `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion. Read from the documentation:

> The return statement is affected by automatic semicolon insertion (ASI). No line terminator is allowed between the return keyword and the expression.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

So your code which returns `undefined` is equivalent with:

```
function arrayFromValue(...item) {
   return;
}
```

After `return` statement the rest of the code will be ignored.

I hope that helps!